# How to combine SVG path like below image

Tags: javascript, html, svg

[image: Actual SVG] Convert to 
[image: Expected SVG]

My Code looks like below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path d="M10 10 L110 10 L110 110 L10 110 Z"  fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="red"/>
  <path d="M110 10 L210 10 L210 110 L110 110 Z"  fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="red"/>
  <path d="M110 110 L210 110 L210 210 L110 210 Z"  fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="red"/>
  
  

  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to convert actual SVG to Expected SVG. I am used the path element for draw each rectangle, i want remove the intersect line while drawing the SVG rect. Can you please suggest any solution.

Comment: There is no easy solution to this. Even if you had a bunch of X,Y Points, and polygons defined by a list of points, joining them like that automatically is a non-trivial problem. First you have to parse each `path`'s `d` attribute into a bunch of connected coordinates. Next you have to keep trying to join two polygons by checking if they have one or more nodes in common. When you can't reduce them further, you need to turn the nodes back into a path. It's of course possible but pretty broad for a SO question I guess.

Answer (score 4):

In this case easy solution would be to code it manually like this:

```html
<svg height="220" width="400" viewBox="0 0 400 220"> 
  <path d="M10,10 L210,10 L210,210 L110,210 L110,110 L10,110  L10,10" stroke="green" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

However for more complicated shapes this won't do. A solution would be removing the stroke from your shapes, fill them with white or whatever color you want and applying  a filter to outline the group of shapes:

```html
<svg height="220" width="400" viewBox="0 0 400 220">
<filter id="outline">
<feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" result="expanded"
operator="dilate" radius="3"/>
<feFlood flood-color="red" result="indi" />
<feComposite in ="indi" in2="expanded" operator="in" />
<feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
  <g fill="white" filter="url(#outline)">
  <path d="M10 10 L110 10 L110 110 L10 110 Z"   />
  <path d="M110 10 L210 10 L210 110 L110 110 Z" />
  <path d="M110 110 L210 110 L210 210 L110 210 Z"  />
</g>  
</svg>
```

I hope it helps.